# Issue with mod_rewrite query string rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

My issue is pretty simple however as I am new to mod_rewrite I seem to be very confused. basically I am trying to make vision friendly urls with mod_rewrite. ie: 'http://example.com/user.php?id=3'  works the same as 'user/7854' etc. i currently have a regex rule as so:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1
```

`phpinfo()` confirms that mod_rewrite is in fact operating/working. My understanding of this is that, if the user is directed to 'http://example.com/user/7854' (for example) The mod_rewrite regex will translate via apache to my php script: 'http://example.com/user.php?id=7854' because anything after 'user/' becomes captured. That being said, this is my user.php:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

now as you can imagine 'http://example.com/user.php?id=7854' displays `7854` however 'http://example.com/user/7854' gives me an error (404) why is this? what have i misunderstood? I've spent an hour on numerous forums just to get this far, this concept isnt coming easy to me at all. cheers to any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @andrea.r says: you have rule for all characters but no numbers.

Change: `RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/$ user.php?id=$1`

to: `RewriteRule ^user/([a-z,0-9]+)/$ user.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 0):

User ID is numerical and you've written `[a-z]` instead of `[0-9]`.

Try this: `RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1`

Comment: EDIT: added backslash before user.php?id=$1

Comment: still no dice (404) on that idea, even tried emptying the cache just in case